# CloudWatch Insights: Filter field contents if matches contents of another field

Tags: syntax, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I'm trying to compare the contents of one ephemeral field to those of another within CloudWatch Logs Insights. The contents are "CompanyRequestID"s, parsed from the log stream @message, and the @requestId in the lambda Report. The requestIds are just strings like 1234-678-5476

In "English" I'm trying to write:

Filter IF contents of parsed-ephemeral-field (CompanyRequestID) equals exactly the contents of @requestId

```
fields @message, @timestamp, @requestId, @billedDuration
| parse @message "XXXX=*, CompanyGeneratedRequestID=*, XXXX=*" as X1, CompanyRequestID, X2 
| display CompanyRequestID, @requestId, @billedDuration
```

As you can see, the fields don't align in the table as they're from different "types".

[Log table at present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cn2jN.png)

I want to essentially (but I can't figure out how):

```
| filter CompanyRequestID = @requestId
| stats sum(@billedDuration)
```

Once I can filter matching requestIds then I can sum the billedduration etc

Thanks in advance! New to this and struggling!